# Android BLE issue: Unsupported transport for background connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working over BLE with some BLE device: discover it first and then trying to connect. However i'm getting the error:

```
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3930/? E/bt-att﹕ Unsupported transport for background connection
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3930/? E/bt-btif﹕ bta_gattc_init_bk_conn failed
```

and i'm unable to connect (note strange status `133` was before disconnected (`0`)):

```
10-03 17:17:45.641  17474-18298/com.icrealtime.allie D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=7 device=08:00:00:3F:B5:F1
```

Full log:

```
10-03 17:17:45.601    1029-1029/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton﹕ onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"IC"
10-03 17:17:45.611  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BleRpcConnectionFactory﹕ Device found: name=Allie-RA222222222, mac_address=08:00:00:3F:B5:F1, other=08:00:00:3F:B5:F1
10-03 17:17:45.621  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BleRpcConnectionFactory﹕ Found and accepted BLE device: 08:00:00:3F:B5:F1
10-03 17:17:45.621  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BleRpcConnectionFactory﹕ Stopping discovery
10-03 17:17:45.621  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-4177/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ stopScan() - queue size =1
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-4052/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ filter size is 1
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-4052/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ delete FilterIndex - 4
10-03 17:17:45.621    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3929/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3929/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3862/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ unregisterClient() - clientIf=7
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-4052/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ stop scan
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-4052/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-4052/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
10-03 17:17:45.621  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BleRpcConnectionFactory﹕ Connecting to device
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-4052/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
10-03 17:17:45.621    3854-3932/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
10-03 17:17:45.631    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
10-03 17:17:45.631  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BluetoothGatt﹕ connect() - device: 08:00:00:3F:B5:F1, auto: true
10-03 17:17:45.631  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BluetoothGatt﹕ registerApp()
10-03 17:17:45.631  17474-17474/com.icrealtime.allie D/BluetoothGatt﹕ registerApp() - UUID=0b2a4a78-aaf0-4c95-832a-b94eb4513795
10-03 17:17:45.631    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-03 17:17:45.631    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
10-03 17:17:45.631    3854-4178/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ registerClient() - UUID=0b2a4a78-aaf0-4c95-832a-b94eb4513795
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3929/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onClientRegistered() - UUID=0b2a4a78-aaf0-4c95-832a-b94eb4513795, clientIf=7
10-03 17:17:45.641  17474-17488/com.icrealtime.allie D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-4177/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ clientConnect() - address=08:00:00:3F:B5:F1, isDirect=false set own addr = false own addr type:0
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3866/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ clientConnect() - address=08:00:00:3F:B5:F1, isDirect=false set own addr = false own addr type:0
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3929/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btif_get_device_type: Device [08:00:00:3f:b5:f1] type 3, addr. type 0
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3930/? E/bt-att﹕ Unsupported transport for background connection
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3930/? E/bt-btif﹕ bta_gattc_init_bk_conn failed
10-03 17:17:45.641    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3929/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btif_get_device_type: Device [08:00:00:3f:b5:f1] type 3, addr. type 0
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3930/? E/bt-btif﹕ bta_gattc_process_api_open Failed, unknown client_if: 0
10-03 17:17:45.641    3854-3929/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onConnected() - clientIf=7, connId=65535, address=08:00:00:3F:B5:F1
10-03 17:17:45.641    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
10-03 17:17:45.641  17474-18298/com.icrealtime.allie D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=7 device=08:00:00:3F:B5:F1
10-03 17:17:45.641  17474-18298/com.icrealtime.allie D/BleRpcConnectionFactory﹕ onConnectionStateChange()
10-03 17:17:45.641    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-03 17:17:45.641    1029-1029/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
10-03 17:17:45.651  17474-20038/com.icrealtime.allie D/BleRpcConnectionFactory﹕ Connection state changed from 133 to 0 for 08:00:00:3F:B5:F1 (08:00:00:3F:B5:F1)
```

What is wrong? I'm sure i start connecting from main thread.

Comment: Hey, have you solved your problem: I'm getting the same error:  `bta_gattc_process_api_open Failed, unknown client_if: 0`

Comment: I too am getting the same error.  Would be nice if you provided the fix you found...

Comment: Is Someone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little experience, if the BLE central is in scanning state, it may need to be stopped scanning before connecting to a peripheral. I encoutnered the 133 error too,https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.1_r13/stack/include/gatt_api.h please checkout here, GATT_ERROR

Logging the the activities can help to debug,

./adb logcat *:S bt-att:* bt-btm:* BluetoothLEint:* BtGatt.ContextMap:*